View (any) binary file in div regardless of type from dataset
I'm looking at this Javascript file (https://github.com/raafacachoeira/jquery-file-viewer/blob/main/fileViewer.js) and trying to modify it to be able to view a file that is stored in a data set.
This script would allow me to view all the file types I currently handle, do it would save me a great deal of time if I could get this to work. I am able to download the file to to the user's download folder, but the security restrictions won't allow the browser to open the file and I wouldn't want to do that anyway.
I can get the file from the back end using Ajax, I'm just not knowledgeable enough with jQuery or Javascript in general to get this or any code I write to display the data in the div. I've been searching all over for any information on the best way to get this done and haven't been able to find anything.
This is my file download code:
Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM"
Dim Header As [String] = "Attachment; Filename=" & MyDataSet.Tables!data.Rows(index)("FileName")
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header)
Response.BinaryWrite(MyDataSet.Tables!data.Rows(index)("document"))
Response.[End]()

I've been using this (and similar code for years), I can convert this easily enough to pull the file out of the database in byte form and get it to the page via Ajax, but how to modify the Javascript to handle the returned file is not working out, I simply cannot make any headway at all. I'd like to modify the Javascript to accept the file data and file attributes (stored in the database) and display it in the viewer which is defined in the div as such:
<div id="viewer" runat="server">
</div>

The script currently accesses a file on disk and the parameters are in the div attributes. I can add attributes via the code behind such as the extension, filename and file type, but the file is the bigger problem, how can I get the file data into the "viewer"?

I can't even get the default setup to run.
